# ASCII Animation for Website like Midjourney

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, ascii

I've come across the [Midjourney Website](https://www.midjourney.com/home/?callbackUrl=%2Fapp%2F) and fell in love with the ASCII Animation.

I've gone through some reddit/stack overflow posts, but couldn't find any useful answers. So I wanted to ask again, is there anyone who knows how to do this with html/css/js? Or even better is there already a useful repository/code?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic idea:

- Create a `div` and put it behind your content like it's a background. Hint: use `position: fixed` and `z-index`
- Query the div element. Use `requestAnimationFrame` to update the text in the div every time the screen is refreshed. Calculate the ASCII frame like how you printed it in you terminal

I wrote some sample JavaScript for you that does some weird animation:

```js
<div id="animation"></div>

let el = document.getElementById("animation")

let i = 0;

const update = () => {
  el.innerText = "\n".repeat(i % 5) + "_".repeat(i % 50) + "Hello"
  i += 1
  requestAnimationFrame(update, 50000)
}

requestAnimationFrame(update, 50000)
```